# How to refer from one active choice reactive parameter to another active choice reactive parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the above images i have used Active choice parameter to select team. Using Active choice reactive parameter i have used "Team" as reference parameter to get the active choices for UseCase. Similarly i want to use an active choice reactive parameter for blueprint to be selected based on the Usecase selected. Is there a way reference from one active choice reactive parameter to another choice reactive parameter ?

Comment: In the exact same way you did it with UseCase

Comment: I tried. But it is not working.

Comment: same here. It looks like groovy cannot be compiled because the referenced parameter is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `CascadeChoiceParameter`, like this:

```
[
        $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        description: 'Blueprint',
        name: 'Blueprint',
        omitValueField: true,
        filterLength: 1,
        filterable: false,
        referencedParameters: 'UseCase',
        randomName: "choice-parameter-${randomNumber}",
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: true,
                script: """return [Error]"""
            ],
            script: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: true,
                script: """
                    if () { return [bla] }
                    """
            ]
        ]
    ]
```